# Shutdown system from a web page when you click a button

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am working on doing a CiberCafe and I need that when the user wants to leave, when the exit button is clicked, the machine will be automatically restarted.

This web I'm doing through html, css, javascript and the electron.js framework.

Anyone know how I can turn off the system when I click on a button?

Comment: you can't do this from a web page because of security. If _you_ could do it, any web page the user browses to could do it, and you certainly wouldn't want that. You don't really need to reboot anyway, you just need to start a new logon session or something. There are some free "internet kiosk" type applications / operating systems out there you can google, maybe one of them will suit your needs. But none of this is something you can do via a web page.

Comment: @ADyson Probably he is trying to do this with electron.js frameworks which wraps a browser inside it.

Comment: @HariDas good point I just assumed electron was yet another web GUI framework. But a quick google suggests that it can be used to build desktop apps. In which case, the app could probably make it log out if there are the correct bindings available to the O/S (I still would say it should log out, not reboot, no need to do that). Not being familiar with the framework I can't say any more than that unfortunately.

Comment: In that case,OP can kill the electron stuff using scripts.I have batch file to kill the electron when It exceeds the time limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Electron framework you have access to more than just the basic html, js.

Create a bat file with the command needed to shutdown

```
c:\windows\system32\shutdown -s -f -t 00 :: shutdown
:: c:\windows\system32\shutdown -r -t 00 :: restart
:: c:\windows\system32\shutdown /h :: hibernate
```

And in the electron side:

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile;
var executablePath = "path_to_bat_file";

child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
       console.error(err);
       return;
    }

    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: I've included your code in electron within a javascript function and called it by clicking a button but doing nothing

Comment: Debug it! It can't 'do nothing' :)) Your comment is not helping me to help you further :)

Comment: I already made it work!
I looked at the item inspection and saw that it had a syntax error.
Thank you for your help has saved me from a hurry!

Answer (score 0):

Because of security reasons this is simply not possible without running something outside of your browser.

If however the page is served from a server and you want to shutdown this server, keep reading:

A solution which would be possible is to run a server in the background, for example node.js.

On your node.js server you could listen for a specific url you are calling, on the trigger of this event you could send a shutdown command to your host. This however opens some security issues, you need to block this call to node from the outside (or not if you want others to be able to shut it down). And your node.js server has to be running with root rights which is also risky.

Take a look at https://github.com/typicode/stop-server maybe you can find something in there that's usefull to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet as far as i can think would be to [download a .bat](http://www.instructables.com/id/Shutdown-restart-or-hibernate-your-computer-on-a/) that would shut down your computer and execute it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function RunFile() {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
    }
</script>
```

Note, this will only work with IE.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP but if I was running a cybercafe I certainly wouldn't want ActiveX enabled. In fact there's a good chance I wouldn't even use Windows. And given that ActiveX hasn't been supported since 2015, and IE is effectively dead now (11 will be the last version), it won't last long as a solution. Also, like me you missed the point that the OP is talking about the electron framework which is used to build desktop apps, so downloading a batch file should be unnecessary, since the app is running on the desktop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For all the above mentioned reasons, the browser **cannot** shutdown the machine. But there are other ways by which the browser can request a trusted application to shutdown (or restart) the machine.

You will need to create server that will run on the same machine. You can create a [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) that will wait for http requests on a certain port.

This python server should be started with appropriate privileges such that it can shut the machine.

Now when you want to shut the machine from the browser, all it has to do is send a HTTP request to loopback on the correct port (to the server). The server will verify the request (whether it is coming from appropriate host etc) and then continue to shut the machine using appropriate system specific command with `os.system`.

You obviously also need the server to be started automatically when the PC restarts. This can be achieved very easily but depends on your operating system and you can find enough resources for the same.

Hope this helps!